# PHP and MySQL user accounts

Tags: php, mysql, apache, webserver, account

I'm very new to both PHP and MySQL.

I have only begun to learn them to run a game server.

The problem I have run into is descriped in apache error log as:

> [Mon Sep 04 01:00:16.928467 2017] [:error] [pid 3656:tid 784] [client 127.0.0.1:49401] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: db in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\sw_game_login.php on line 24
>
> [Mon Sep 04 01:00:16.928467 2017] [:error] [pid 3656:tid 784] [client 127.0.0.1:49401] PHP Stack trace:
>
> [Mon Sep 04 01:00:16.928467 2017] [:error] [pid 3656:tid 784] [client 127.0.0.1:49401] PHP   1. {main}() C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\sw_game_login.php:0
>
> [Mon Sep 04 01:00:16.928467 2017] [:error] [pid 3656:tid 784] [client 127.0.0.1:49401] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_row() on null in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\sw_game_login.php on line 24
>
> [Mon Sep 04 01:00:16.928467 2017] [:error] [pid 3656:tid 784] [client 127.0.0.1:49401] PHP Stack trace:
>
> [Mon Sep 04 01:00:16.928467 2017] [:error] [pid 3656:tid 784] [client 127.0.0.1:49401] PHP   1. {main}() C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\sw_game_login.php:0

line 24 of sw_game_login.php looks like the following:

> if(list($id)=$db->fetch_row($db->query("SELECT ID FROM accounts WHERE ACCOUNT_NAME='$account' AND ACCOUNT_PASSWORD='$pass'"))){

The error I receive from my game client says that incorrect account or password, I know this is not the case I have tried several and checked several times. Thus leading me to believe that maybe the request is not being sent through properly.

Thanks in advance to any help!

Answer (score 1):

According to your error log, your db variable is undefined. Add this to the top of your sw_game_login.php script.

```
if (!isset($db))
    $db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

Comment: Maybe we should teach about input validation/sanitization while you are at it ? :)